# c# windows forms / basic data grid

Tags: c#, forms

One of the problems I am having with c# is that there seems to be so much information online that I am having trouble finding the right answer to the most basic of questions.

I am trying to do something simple:
I have a button, I click it, it queries the database and populates a datagrid on my windows form.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (local); Integrated Security = true; Initial Catalog = pubs;  "); 

        c.Open();
        // 2
        // Create new DataAdapter
        SqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @" SELECT * FROM Authors ";
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = reader;
        dataGridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found.....

I am probably missing a "using directive" but which one? Multiple Google searches tell me how to bind a Yahoo RSS Feed to a gridview or provide various obscure details on "using directives".

Maybe I am using the SqlDataReader incorrectly. Should I be using SqlAdapter instead? What happened to all the good basic tutorials online for windows c# forms? A few months ago I found a couple great tutorials, but they seem to have lost their pageranking and I cannot find them anymore using basic google searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Authors", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

The DataGridView does not have a DataBind() method because it doesn't need one.  Setting the DataSource property handles the binding for you.  The using() blocks will automatically close and dispose of everything for you as well.

**Note**: you should replace "your connection string" with a valid connection string. I left yours out of my sample to avoid the horizontal scrollbars, and I'm not sure yours is valid anyway.  You may get a runtime error when you run the code using your connection string.  [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) is a great resource for figuring out a valid connection string.

**Update**:  instead of the nested using() blocks, you can also do it like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@" SELECT * FROM Authors", conn))
using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adap.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

I prefer the nested style, but it's "half of one, six dozen of the other" to me.  Typically, I would encapsulate code like this into a class (called "DataGetter" or whatever) with a static method like:

```
public static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    // do all the connecting and adapting and filling and so forth
}
```

so that the code in your button click would be as simple as:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = DataGetter.GetData("SELECT * FROM AUTHORS");
```

However, I would *not* do this in any performance-critical section of my code, since you sometimes want to keep a SqlCommand object (and its SqlParameter collection) around between calls.  You do *not* need to keep SqlConnection objects around between calls, thanks to connection pooling (in fact, you don't want to keep them around under any circumstances).

Comment: Thank you, that is the syntax I was looking for but had trouble finding through searching on google.

Is it common practice to nest the "Using" statements like that?

Comment: It's common practice for me, but you can also do it like in my update.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot and the datagrid is working now. Bookmarked it for future reference.

Comment: In your 2nd example, you "use" an `SqlConnection`, an `SqlCommand`, and then an `SqlDataAdapter`. Since the `SqlDataAdapter` contains its own `SqlCommand`, I typically omit the `SqlCommand` when using the `SqlDataAdapter` which gives the added benefit of not having to manage the `SqlConnection` State. Would there be a reason for using the `SqlCommand` object specifically for this case, or are you simply trying to provide a complete example? Just curious.

Comment: @jp2code: the ADO.NET architects were big fans of constructor overloads, so there are often many different ways of writing code to perform a given task (that all end up doing exactly the same thing under the hood). In general, I prefer to explicitly spell out the steps involved in something - in fact, I had to stop myself from putting `conn.Close()` in my examples. :)

Answer (score 4):

You're not missing a using directive; it's just that the WinForms [DataGridView doesn't have a DataBind method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_members.aspx).  Just assigning DataSource is enough to get the binding to happen; you don't need to call a method as well.

However, I don't think you can assign a SqlDataReader as the DataSource.  According to the [DataSource property documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx), the DataSource must be an IList, an IListSource, an IBindingList or an IBindingListView.  You will probably instead need to load the data into a DataTable or DataSet (or an object data source populated using an object-relational mapper), and use that as the DataSource.

Comment: Okay, so I should use "SqlDataAdapter"? How do I bind the dataset to the datagrid?

Comment: Yes.  Per MusiGenesis' comment, use SqlDataAdapter to load the DataTable or DataSet, then bind by setting the DataSource property to the DataTable or DataSet.