# Select Query sql C# how to output the results to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

How do I output results from a refined query to a datagrid view called "customerDataGridView"?

```
string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.PID2dbConnectionString;

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon)) {
   conn.Open();
   string strSql = "SELECT  * FROM customer WHERE City =Belfast";
   OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn));
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this for ASP.Net:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, connection);
oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
customerDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);
customerDataGridView.DataBind();
```

Or something like this for WinForms:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, connection);
oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
customerDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);
```

Good luck.

Comment: under ".databind();" and "ds.Tables(0);" i get an eror saying "Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'Databind' and no extension method 'Databind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

Comment: i dont seem to have anything like that, the closest thing to DataBind i have  is DataBindings, maby im missing a libary?

Comment: Are you using WinForms?  If so, check this link out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

Comment: yes, sorry i didnt mention it in the orginal post. ok thanks il check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try the following after your code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
customerDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True
customerDataGridView.Datasource = table;
```

Comment: under ".databind();" i get an eror saying "Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'Databind' and no extension method 'Databind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

Comment: Try removing the Databind(), you may not need it in windows forms. But make sure to set the dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True. Referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449773/c-sharp-windows-forms-basic-data-grid. They say that the datasource handles the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter oda = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, conn);
oda.Fill(ds);
customerDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);
```

For winform control you don't need `DataBind()`